# Dynamic tab with dynamic select input option- R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny application. It is almost completed.

I need to hide one tab dynamically. But this tab also has one dynamic `selectInput` option.

I am able to only hide a tab when it does not have any dynamic input selection.
Here I am confused that if in UI part I am using for example:

```
htmlOutput("selectUI"))
```

for Dynamic tab then where should I mention

```
htmlOutput("selectUI1"))
```

for dynamic `selectInput` option.

Please assist. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `shinyjs` package has `show` and `hide` methods, look into that

Comment: I have one doubt here.To access any tabsetPanel,we use its 'id' but for a single tabPanel what we can use.